# Multiple image slider on hover not clickable using onClick()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have this code and it works fine on the image on hover, it plays the images fine, but if i try to click on it to get forward to the link i want to get forward it does not work. Any tips please.

here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>test</title>
<meta name="description" content=""/>

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />


<style>

body{background-color:#000}

.img-wrapper{
width: 300px;
height: 400px;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
cursor:pointer
}
.img-wrapper img{
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
position: absolute;
-webkit-animation: showMe 1.6s linear infinite 0s forwards;
-moz-animation: showMe 1.6s linear infinite 0s forwards;
-o-animation: showMe 1.6s linear infinite 0s forwards;
-ms-animation: showMe 1.6s linear infinite 0s forwards;
animation: showMe 1.6s linear infinite 0s forwards;
-webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
-moz-animation-play-state: paused;
-o-animation-play-state: paused;
-ms-animation-play-state: paused;
animation-play-state: paused;   
}
.img-wrapper img:nth-child(1){
z-index: 9;
}
.img-wrapper img:nth-child(2){
-webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
-moz-animation-delay: 0.2s;
-o-animation-delay: 0.2s;
-ms-animation-delay: 0.2s;
animation-delay: 0.2s;
z-index: 8;
}
 .img-wrapper img:nth-child(3){
-webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
-moz-animation-delay: 0.4s;
-o-animation-delay: 0.4s;
-ms-animation-delay: 0.4s;
animation-delay: 0.4s;
z-index: 7;
}
.img-wrapper img:nth-child(4){
-webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
-moz-animation-delay: 0.6s;
-o-animation-delay: 0.6s;
-ms-animation-delay: 0.6s;
animation-delay: 0.6s;
z-index: 6;
}
.img-wrapper img:nth-child(5){
-webkit-animation-delay: 0.8s;
-moz-animation-delay: 0.8s;
-o-animation-delay: 0.8s;
-ms-animation-delay: 0.8s;
animation-delay: 0.8s;
z-index: 5;
}
.img-wrapper img:nth-child(6){
-webkit-animation-delay: 1.0s;
-moz-animation-delay: 1.0s;
-o-animation-delay: 1.0s;
-ms-animation-delay: 1.0s;
animation-delay: 1.0s;
z-index: 4;
}
.img-wrapper img:nth-child(7){
-webkit-animation-delay: 1.2s;
-moz-animation-delay: 1.2s;
-o-animation-delay: 1.2s;
-ms-nimation-delay: 1.2s;
animation-delay: 1.2s;
z-index: 3;
}
.img-wrapper img:nth-child(8){
-webkit-animation-delay: 1.4s;
-moz-animation-delay: 1.4s;
-o-animation-delay: 1.4s;
-ms-animation-delay: 1.4s;
animation-delay: 1.4s;
z-index: 2;
}
.img-wrapper:hover img{
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
-moz-animation-play-state: running;
-o-animation-play-state: running;
-ms-animation-play-state: running;
animation-play-state: running;
}



@-webkit-keyframes showMe {
0% { visibility: visible; z-index: 100; }
12.5% { visibility: visible; z-index: 100; }
25% { visibility: hidden; z-index: 0; }
100% { visibility: hidden; z-index: 0; }
}

@-moz-keyframes showMe {
0% { visibility: visible; z-index: 100; }
12.5% { visibility: visible; z-index: 100; }
25% { visibility: hidden; z-index: 0; }
100% { visibility: hidden; z-index: 0; }
}

@-o-keyframes showMe {
0% { visibility: visible; z-index: 100; }
12.5% { visibility: visible; z-index: 100; }
25% { visibility: hidden; z-index: 0; }
100% { visibility: hidden; z-index: 0; }
}

@-ms-keyframes showMe {
0% { visibility: visible; z-index: 100; }
12.5% { visibility: visible; z-index: 100; }
25% { visibility: hidden; z-index: 0; }
100% { visibility: hidden; z-index: 0; }
}

@keyframes showMe {
0% { visibility: visible; z-index: 100; }
12.5% { visibility: visible; z-index: 100; }
25% { visibility: hidden; z-index: 0; }
100% { visibility: hidden; z-index: 0; }
}





</style>

</head>

<body>
<!--Top Bar Starts-->


<div class="img-wrapper" id="beachtrain">

<img src="btns/hover1.png" alt="image01"/>
<img src="btns/hover2.png" alt="image02"/>
<img src="btns/hover3.png" alt="image03"/>
<img src="btns/hover1.png" alt="image04"/>
<img src="btns/hover2.png" alt="image05"/>
<img src="btns/hover3.png" alt="image06"/>
<img src="btns/hover2.png" alt="image07"/>
<img src="btns/hover3.png" alt="image08"/>




</div>











    <script>
        $("#beachtrain").click(function() {
  window.location.href = 'http://www.google.co.uk'
});
    </script>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should wrap your jquery in a $(function(){ block

Comment: ok how can i fix it? please....

Comment: i still want to work on hover but by clickable

Comment: See my answer. also make sure you're including jquery inside your head tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you just left it out, but your script at the bottom is using jquery and you don't have jquery included. If you don't want to use it, go with this:

```
<script>
    var myElement = document.getElementById('beachtrain');
    myElement.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        window.location.href = 'http://www.google.co.uk'
    });
</script>
```

Is there any reason you're using this instead of just making your beachtrain element a link? That'd be the cleanest solution. See below for an example:

```
<a href="http://www.google.co.uk" class="img-wrapper" id="beachtrain" style="display:block;">
  <img src="btns/hover1.png" alt="image01"/>
  <img src="btns/hover2.png" alt="image02"/>
  <img src="btns/hover3.png" alt="image03"/>
  <img src="btns/hover1.png" alt="image04"/>
  <img src="btns/hover2.png" alt="image05"/>
  <img src="btns/hover3.png" alt="image06"/>
  <img src="btns/hover2.png" alt="image07"/>
  <img src="btns/hover3.png" alt="image08"/>
</a>
```

Comment: I try this one but it didn't work. I started as an image that on hover will fade in more then 1 image...however at the time i make the <a></a> to the image the hover effect doesn't work anymore....the forward to the new url does but the effect doesn't. therefore i try using a different way....

Comment: This one actually works if you click on the div several times....at some point it forwards you to url...still not working the way it should....any ideas....i appreciate your help.

Comment: I mean change img-wrapper into a link - I tried it and it worked for me! See above for another snippet.

Comment: Safari gives a problem you have to click multiple times to make it go

Comment: And the script above the HTML example didn't work either? If all else fails, you can add an onclick event to each image....like this  onclick="window.location.href='http://www.google.co.uk'"

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your script code in a document.ready block. In jquery you can do it with a shortcut:

```
$(function(){
    $('#beachtrain').click(function(){
        // your code 
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry really new to this

Comment: any version...i suggest using a cdn. please remember to accept the answer if i was able to help you. best of luck!